# Create Blog for Every Site Owner

Tags: 2013, blog

There is a site collection ready. Now I plan that every site owners will have their own blog.

The site owners can edit their own blog and view others blog.

How can I create a blog for every site owner like it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I created mysite for everyone under a site collection. Here are the links that I followed:

http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2012/07/25/visual-guide-setting-up-my-sites-in-sharepoint-2013/

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/01/03/how-to-set-up-people-search-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx